# Hide Wordpress Meta Boxes when selecting Categories

Tags: wordpress

I am creating custom meta boxes in wp-admin which contain custom fields.

```
    function createCustomFieldsTwo() {
        if ( function_exists( 'add_meta_box' ) ) {
            add_meta_box( 'my-custom-fields-OpInfo', 'Operator Information', array( &$this, 'displayCustomFieldsOpInfo' ), 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
            add_meta_box( 'my-custom-fields-OpInfo', 'Operator Information', array( &$this, 'displayCustomFieldsOpInfo' ), 'post', 'normal', 'high' );

        }
    }
```

I am trying to hide certain meta boxes when user selects certain categories, I believe this is possible with Jquery but am unsure on how to proceed.

Does anyone have experience with hiding / showing meta boxes depending on post category?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the global post object and run a query...

```
function createCustomFieldsTwo() {
  if ( function_exists( 'add_meta_box' ) ) {
    global $post;
    $category = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category', array("fields" => "names"));
    // If not the category you want to hide the meta box on
    if(isset($category[0]->name) && $category[0]->name != 'Desired category') {
      add_meta_box( 'my-custom-fields-OpInfo', 'Operator Information', array( &$this, 'displayCustomFieldsOpInfo' ), 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
    }
  }
}
```

Or a similar type of query on the post object to find out what category it is - oh and you might want to add in some isset() in there as well to avoid errors :)

Comment: would this add / hide meta boxes live as user selected different categories or only on page load?

Comment: On page load - to do it with JS then its simple enough - just look at .Change https://api.jquery.com/change/ the first parameter you pass to add_meta_box is the id of the box in admin so you can see what the value of the category is on .change and show / hide the id of the meta box div as needed